# Which kind of binding does existing between Customer and RabbitMQ broker?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am beginner in RabbitMQ, I have started my adventure from essentials in official site of RabbitMQ.

Now I have got the following schema of using broker messager at the layers:

```
Backend Server(Business logic) -> (push message) -> RabbitMQ -> Customer(receiver).
```

Concerning this logic I have simple question: Which kind of binding does existing between Customer and RabbitMQ broker and between `Backend Server` and `RabbitMQ Broker` if these physical components are placed on different servers? Is it sockets layer or stateless HTTP connection?

Schema that illustrates my thought is:

```
 Backend Server(Business logic) ->(???) -> (push message) -> RabbitMQ -> (???) Customer(receiver).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a socket-level, binary protocol called `AMQP`, version `0-9-1`.

The specification can be found at RMQ's site: https://www.rabbitmq.com/amqp-0-9-1-reference.html, you can see these methods reflected in e.g. Java API.

Comment: Is it integrated in RabbitMQ by default? Or it is necessary to build intermediate custom layer?

Comment: Yes, it is, you do not need to build anything underneath.

Comment: Okayç then how client like mobile device joins to broker?

Comment: The same way as any other client would - you need to establish a TCP connection with broker and follow the protocol. Means your broker must be publicly accessible. The Java example is `com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory`.

Comment: So, if I have Android or Ios apps I need to deploy client side for them?

Comment: Yes. By your question I see you might be interested in `STOMP` instead of `AMQP`, that's still supported by RMQ - https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html

Comment: What does do this plugin? I actually didn't get it

Answer (score 1):

A consumer consumes messages from a queue, you do not need to care about bindings from the consumer.

Messages, however, are not published directly to a queue, instead, the producer sends messages to an exchange. Exchanges are message routing agents, defined per virtual host within RabbitMQ. An exchange is responsible for the routing of the messages to the different queues. An exchange accepts messages from the producer application and routes them to message queues with help of header attributes, bindings, and routing keys.

A binding is a "link" that you set up to bind a queue to an exchange.

The routing key is a message attribute. The exchange might look at this key when deciding how to route the message to queues (depending on exchange type).

In RabbitMQ, there are four different types of exchange that routes the message differently using different parameters and bindings setups.

More information can be found here: https://www.cloudamqp.com/blog/2015-09-03-part4-rabbitmq-for-beginners-exchanges-routing-keys-bindings.html

[image]

Comment: What channel are used between Queues and Consumer?